# Removing space between open bracket "(" and reference

Tags: ieeetran

I am writting a paper in IEEE format. For one sentence, i have two references and therefore i want to show them in a bracket e.g. `([1], [2])` but i am not able to get that format.

Instead of `([1], [2])` , i am getting `( [1], [2])`.

So, how can i remove the extra space between "(" and first "[" as depicted in the screenshot below.

***My code:***

**Main.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt,ieeeconf]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\graphicspath{{../pdf/}{/home/xyz/Desktop/rightwards}}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[all,graph]{xy}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\title{Effect of the Position}
\author
{\IEEEauthorblockN{Xyz}\\
\IEEEauthorblockA{Lab, Faculty of Electrical Engineering \\
University of ABC\\
xyz@mail.de}
}
\markboth{Engineering Paper}{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\input{introduction}

\bibliography{refer.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

**introduction.tex**

this is introduction of a paper (\cite{firstPaper}, \cite{secondPaper}).

[image]

Comment: Please show us an MWE (minimum working example -- a LaTeX program that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` -- that generates the problem behavior you're encountering. Without such information it's going to be very difficult to diagnose what's going on, let alone propose a fix.

Comment: Use `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}`

Comment: `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}` solved the problem. Thanks